# How to display an imagebutton on a surfaceview

Tags: android, android-layout, surfaceview, android-framelayout

I want to draw a wave on a surfaceview when recording and show a `ImageButton` on the `SurfaceView` at the end. I used `FrameLayout`.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/sfv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:background="#464646" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ib_delete"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/record_delete" />

</FrameLayout>
```

At the end of recording, I use the method

```
ib_delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

But it does not work. How can I solve this problem？

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"?

Comment: The imagebutton does not show.

Comment: First things first: if you remove `android:visibility="gone"`, does it appear? I'm trying to establish whether the issue is with the use of the `visibility` tag or something else.